# SQL rows into repeating columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this data:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7
0062|date|501|text1|text1|text1|text1
0062|date|502|text2|text2|text2|text2       
0062|date|503|text3|text3|text3|text3       
0063|date|501|text1|text1|text1|text1       
0063|date|502|text2|text2|text2|text2
0063|date|503|text3|text3|text3|text3
```

I would like to have it like this:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7
0062|date|501|text1|text1|text1|text1|502|text2|text2|text2|text2|503|text3|text3|text3|text3
0063|date|501|text1|text1|text1|text1|502|text2|text2|text2|text2|503|text3|text3|text3|text3
```

etc.

How can I do this in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 with a SQL Server 2008 R2 database?

I think I have to do something with pivot, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: What database? And of course, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you know that there are always three sets of rows (501, 502, 503)?  Or can this vary?  If the latter, then you need a dynamic pivot, which requires using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Double self FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: I created a sqlfiddle for testing http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ccd93/1

Comment: @GordonLinoff How would you write the pivot if you assume only (501, 502, 503) ? Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Double self `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1),
       t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5, t1.col6, t1.col7,
       t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5, t2.col6, t2.col7,
       t3.col2, t3.col3, t3.col4, t3.col5, t3.col6, t3.col7
from (select * from mytable where col3 = 501) as t1
full outer join (select * from mytable where col3 = 502) as t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
full outer join (select * from mytable where col3 = 503) as t3 on t2.col1 = t3.col1
```

ANSI SQL syntax. Don't know if SQL Server supports it or not.

Comment: You can make this generic using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col3 `

Comment: @ughai, Thanks for the tip. I know there are lots of SQL Server functionality I need to learn!

Comment: I think that should be it, with partiion because the FULL OUTER JOIN is not working for me. The select right of JOIN will give all results of the 500K rows while I only need the one where co1=t1.col but t1.col gives an error.

Comment: I'm stuck, I can't get it the way I want it.
I'm can't figure out how to use partition. Can someone give me a clear example with the table in the OP?